# Using Incheon’s Transit Hotel

Tags: transit, luggage, layovers, hotels, south-korea

I’m going to have a 12 hour layover in Incheon in April and was planning on using their terminal 2 transit hotel. Their hotel policy states that I cannot use them if I have to go through immigration and customs for my checked baggage, which I think I’ll have to do. However, if my departing flight is still in the same terminal, I should be able to just check back in, receiving a new boarding pass, and use the hotel, correct?

Comment: You may have trouble getting into the security line the day before your flight departs. (Dropping off your checked bag the day before is also often not allowed).